# pythons lxml.html, grab all at once

Tags: python, lxml.html

Using lxml.html, I was able to get the data-pid using 
`fromstring(source).xpath('/html/body/article/section/div[1]/div[2]/p[2]')[0].get('data-pid')`

However, it only returns one of them (in this case 4559733570). I recall being able to grab all of them at once, but I don't remember how. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

HTML Code looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQKsQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your png and xpath query, it seems like all the `<p>` elements you are interested in are nested in the same `<div>`. The xpath query `/html/body/article/section/div[1]/div[2]/p[2]` will return only the second `<p>` element in the selected div (`[2]`). If you want all the paragraphs in the div, use `/html/body/article/section/div[1]/div[2]/p`.

```
[ p.get("data-pid") for p in fromstring(source).xpath('/html/body/article/section/div[1]/div[2]/p') ]
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at. I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Great! I fixed the code anyways, I had forgotten to remove the .get when I pasted.

Answer (score 0):

## xpath, directly returning all the values

Assuming you care about attributes `data-pid` in all `p` elements:

```
>>> fromstring(source).xpath("//p/@data-pi")
```

shall return what you need.

Comment: Still prints the first element only

Comment: @user42992 I have modified xpath by removing last index and added another xpath selector, which is likely to select what you need (all "p" elements having `data-pid`.

Comment: @user42992 Finally I simplified the solution into single xpath.